# Xephyr with evdev on SLES 12 SP3

Tags: linux, touch, suse, sles, evdev

I have two touch screen devices currently working in SLES 12 SP3. What I would like to do is have Xephyr run a separate (essentially multiseat) window on the second monitor with it's own touch screen independent of the main screen.

Issue being, I cannot seem to get Xephyr to grab/allow touch. The command I'm using are as follows:

```
Xephyr -ac -br -noreset -screen 1280x800 :1 -mouse evdev,,/device=/dev/input/by-id/usb-ILITEK_ILITEK-TP_V06.00.00.02-if01-event-mouse
```

Output of /dev/input/by-id/:

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Apr  9 10:56 usb-Generic_USB_Audio_201405280001-event-if03 -> ../event16
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  9 Apr  9 10:56 usb-HP_HP_USB_Encryption_MSR_730T802038-event-kbd -> ../event4
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Apr  9 10:56 usb-ILITEK_ILITEK-TP_V06.00.00.02-event-if00 -> ../event12
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Apr  9 10:56 usb-ILITEK_ILITEK-TP_V06.00.00.02-if01-event-mouse -> ../event13
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  9 Apr  9 10:56 usb-ILITEK_ILITEK-TP_V06.00.00.02-if01-mouse -> ../mouse3
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Apr  9 10:56 usb-ILITEK_ILITEK-TP_V06.02.00.02-event-if00 -> ../event11
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  9 Apr  9 10:56 usb-ILITEK_ILITEK-TP_V06.02.00.02-if01-event-mouse -> ../event5
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  6 Apr  9 10:56 usb-ILITEK_ILITEK-TP_V06.02.00.02-if01-mouse -> ../js0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Apr  9 11:18 usb-Lite-On_Tech_IBM_USB_Keyboard_with_UltraNav-event-if01 -> ../event15
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Apr  9 11:18 usb-Lite-On_Tech_IBM_USB_Keyboard_with_UltraNav-event-kbd -> ../event14
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Apr  9 11:18 usb-Synaptics_Inc._Composite_TouchPad___TrackPoint-event-mouse -> ../event17
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Apr  9 11:18 usb-Synaptics_Inc._Composite_TouchPad___TrackPoint-if01-event-mouse -> ../event18
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  9 Apr  9 11:18 usb-Synaptics_Inc._Composite_TouchPad___TrackPoint-if01-mouse -> ../mouse5
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  9 Apr  9 11:18 usb-Synaptics_Inc._Composite_TouchPad___TrackPoint-mouse -> ../mouse4
```

I've gotten touch events to read via "ILITEK_ILITEK-TP_V06.00.00.02" but the actual 'mouse presses' (aka taps) are still not registering and nothing appears to be selectable.